# Are questions with title opposite to text ok?

Tags: discussion, questions

There are a large number of questions like [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46188/15469) ("Does a Warforged barbarian get fatigued?") one or [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49224/can-a-summoner-cast-the-summon-monster-spell-with-his-eidolon-out) ("Can a Summoner Cast the Summon Monster Spell With His Eidolon Out?"), where the question asked in the title is the opposite of the one asked in the text of the question, i.e. a 'yes' to the question in the title is equivalent to a 'no' to the question in the text.

Personally, I find this confusing when answering, even though very few answers stop at a simple yes or no. So, are questions like these a problem? (The irony is intentional.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not ideal when that mismatch exists, and you're right to call it out that it makes the question confusing. They ought to be edited to be brought in line.

Answers should still preferably say more than **Yes.** at the beginning, so that we know exactly what they're saying yes *to.* **Yes, X happens.** is generally better communication.

Comment: It's also probably worth mentioning that we now have a badge for editing questions near to when you've answered them well. If there's an obvious mismatch, bring a question in line with maximal clarity.

Comment: I try to headline answers without using yes or no at all. That way, if the question is corrected later, my answer still stands. `:-)` Further, when I pose a question, I try to give users the option to answer it in a way that doesn't reflect the question's preconceived notions; I've asked too many question that I thought were yes or no only to learn that the answer is actually lava, 42, or weasels.

Answer (score -2):

You ask:

> Are questions with title opposite to text ok?

### No, they are not OK

If the person asking the question can't put the effort into getting what's in the question and what's in the title to match, then close the question as "unclear" until they clarify and they match.

Let's not make this harder on question answerers than it needs to be.

Comment: The easier solution seems to be to just edit either the title to match the body or vice versa. That's what I've generally done. It's also what doppelgreener's answer suggests in the first paragraph.

Comment: @V2Blast I often do that, but quite frankly, that's us engaging in enabling behavior.  Whomever has the question ought to put the effort into that fundamental concept taught to us in 8th grade or before; make the title and the topic match.

Comment: I assume part of the issue is that querents are prompted to enter the title before they write the body of the post - and they often don't go back and rewrite the title afterwards. Regardless, I wouldn't call this any more "enabling" than editing the post to fix its grammar or edit in a relevant tag. It seems more productive to me to edit the post as needed when it's such an easily solved problem, and then leave a comment explaining what you edited and why so that they can avoid doing it in the future. I don't see it as a major issue unless the user keeps doing it repeatedly after being told.

Comment: (That is to say: It seems better to teach by example rather than close the question for such a minor issue that we know how to solve ourselves.)

Comment: @V2Blast It's been an issue that has bothered me for about 4 years.